# Recognize the words "AND" and "OR" into a string

Tags: python, text-parsing

Assume that I have a string like this:

```
x = "Romeo and Juliet"
```

I would like to separate the two names "Romeo" and "Juliet" by recognizing the keyword "and", for example creating an output list:

```
y = ["Romeo", "Juliet"]
```

What it matters is that however the word "and" is written (examples: AND, And, aNd, anD etc.) shouldn't bring confusion to the interpreter that will understand it means "and" and will split the two words anyway. I have sorted with a horrible solution like this:

```
y = []
i = 0
tmpString = ""
while x[i] != " ":
    tmpString = tmpString + x[i]
    i += 1

i += 1
if x[i:i+3] == 'and' or x[i:i+3] == 'aNd': #and all the other cases...
y.append(tmpString)
tmpString = ""
i += 4
while i < len(x):
    tmpString = tmpString + x[i] 
y.append(tmpString)
```

Of course I could make the algorithm a bit more complex (to take into account the cases when there are more than just two names, when it's a "or" rather than an "and" etc.) but I don't really like the idea of iterating so many times through the string. Moreover I'm very new to Python, and I didn't understand how to use these modules and methods such as "evaluate", or "parsing" etc. 
Does anyone have any suggestion to make a nicer and more flexible algorithm?

Comment: `if x[i:i+3] == 'and' or x[i:i+3] == 'aNd': #and all the other cases...` => `if x[i:i+3].lower() == 'and':`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'\s+AND\s+', 'Romeo AnD Juliet', flags=re.I) # re.I tells Python to ignore case
['Romeo', 'Juliet']
```

If you want to split on AND or OR, then you can change the regexp a bit:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?:AND|OR)\s+', 'Romeo Or Juliet', flags=re.I)
['Romeo', 'Juliet']
```

Comment: This is the approach I'd take: You can further improve by using word boundaries (althoug having said that - this works better for trimming surrounding strings!) - and the OP mentions splitting by "and" or "or", so can do both, something like: `r'\band|or\b'` should work nicely I think

Comment: Good suggestion on `and|or` (although your regexp would match on "Romeo xor Juliet"). Regarding `\b`, let's agree to disagree: splitting with `\b` will require to strip the strings off the spaces and I don't feel like stripping today. It's just a matter of taste really.

Comment: All answers were worthy but this one is really what I was looking for. Straight, flexible, complete, works with spaces and doesn't matter how many names are inside. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions to do this. Here is an example:

```
>>> import re
>>> import string
>>> x = "Romeo and Juliet"
>>> map(string.strip, re.split(r"\bAND\b", x, flags=re.I))
['Romeo', 'Juliet']
```

Comment: Very similar to Neil's approach... It's worth noting that `string` is deprecated for pretty much everything but a few auxillary less-oft used functions and constants so it's preferred to use the methods on the str object itself - `str.strip` in this example.

Comment: @JonClements Correct. I just wanted to avoid the little overhead of a `lambda`, hence used `string.strip`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me... use `str.strip` instead of `string.strip` :p (The vast majority of the methods in the `string` module are on the `str` object itself now...)

Comment: Just for completeness, the solution with `str.strip` would be `map(lambda s: s.strip(), re.split(r"\bAND\b", x, flags=re.I))`

Comment: No - it wouldn't... it would be `map(str.strip, ...)` - you don't need the `lambda` and you don't need the `string` module...

Comment: Ahh. Don't know how I forgot about the `str` type :) I was thinking about the str objects. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 3):

Try this comprehension:

```
>>> x = "Romeo and Juliet"
>>> y = [word for word in x.split() if word.lower() != "and"]
>>> y
['Romeo', 'Juliet']
>>> x = "Romeo aND Juliet"
>>> y = [word for word in x.split() if word.lower() != "and"]
>>> y
['Romeo', 'Juliet']
```

The key is applying `lower()` when you compare your word to the key.  This normalizes what you might find into a form you'd can expect.  So even if `key = "aND"` or `key = "AnD"`, `key.lower() = "and"` regardless.

Just for completeness, you could do this with functions other than `lower()` and end up with an equivalent solution so long as your key matches.  Some examples:

- `y = [word for word in x.split() if word.title() != "And"]`
- `y = [word for word in x.split() if word.upper() != "AND"]`

**Some notes:**

- As Sunny Nada pointed out, this approach gives less than ideal results if the names ahve spaces (`x = "Joe Smith and Tom" >>> ["Joe", "Smith", "Tom"]`).  If this is not what you want, you'll need a more robust method (like `re`)
- To make your approach work you could change `if x[i:i+3] == 'and' or x[i:i+3] == 'aNd':` to `if x[i:i+3] in ["and", "AND", "aNd", ...etc]:`.  This approach is typically considered better form for testing multiple values (`or` conditions).  Alternatively, you could use the `if` statement that I use in my comprehension and get similar results (`if x[i:i+3].lower() == "and":`)

One final suggestion (mostly for fun) which will work with multi-word names and avoids `re`

```
>>> y = map(lambda s: s.strip(), map(lambda s: s.title(), x.lower().split('and')))
>>> y
['Romeo', 'Juliet']
```

Note that this is probably an abuse of `map()` and `lambda` functions

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to explain to OP what `word.lower()` does? :)

Comment: This won't work if there is a name with spaces in it. Try this with `x = "Romeo Sherman and Juliet Sherman"`